# GoogleMaps on Ionic5 messing up Swipe Modal

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I’m having issues with the GoogleMaps and the new *‘swipe to close’* modal.
My issue is that the class `_gmaps_cdv_` that gets attached to the `body` by GoogleMaps is changing the background color to white. The effect looks weird and bad.

I’ve tried pretty much everything…

1. Removing the class once the modal gets loaded. That will make the map disappear and take whatever color I’ve set to the background.
2. Removing the class once the modal gets loaded and attaching it again once the modal gets destroyed. Same result as previous
3. Destroying the map on the ionViewWillLeave() and recreating using the ionViewWIllLoad(). Same result as previous.

Any tips? Is this a bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got around this. The solution is pretty simple. The background color can be setup on the `Environment` class of the GoogleMaps.

Make sure the `Environment` is imported on your component and do as follows:

```
// If you're following the documentation, there should be more things imported here, because I'm focusing on the Environment, I will only use this one.
import { Environment } from '@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx';

ngOninit() {
   Environment.setBackgroundColor('black'); // Or whatever color you want.
}
```

That's it!
Here is the documentation link for reference:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/environment/README.md